# pcntl_signal on a global variable/object (php)

Tags: php, signals

I'm trying to catch a signal (ie SIGUSR1) and call a function from an object.

```
class obj {
...
  public function debug() {
    var_dump($this->varfoo);
  }
}

$o = new obj();
declare(ticks = 1);
function sig_handler($signo) {
    switch ($signo) {
        case SIGUSR1:
            echo "Caught SIGUSR1...\n";
            $o->debug();
            break;
        default:
            // handle all other signals
    }
}
pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, "sig_handler");
```

As soon as I send the signal, I get a php fatal error:
Call to a member function debug();

So, I tried something else:

Instead of that:

```
function sig_handler($signo) {
...
}

pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, "sig_handler");
```

I used that:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, function ($signal, $o) {
    echo gettype($o); //this prints null, I was hoping for object
    echo "Caught SIGUSR1...\n";
    $o->debug();
});
```

I know it doesn't look right, but I can't figure out how to pass the $o inside the signal handler.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It worked by adding the handler inside the class like this:

```
class obj {
...
public function __construct() {
    ...
    pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, function ($signal) { 
        echo "Caught SIGUSR1...\n";
        $this->debug();
    });
}
```

Not sure if it's the best way, but seems to be working.